# Button onclick not executing correctly

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have an xpages with 2 controls.

A tabbed control which gives the user to change between pages and a content control which obviously changes.

Now I needed to implement a change listener which prevents the change of pages when a value is not correct. When the CSJS checks the fields and sets a flag that the document is dirty ( aka changed ) the following code is execute:

```
document.getElementById("#{id:button1}").click();
thisEvent.preventDefault();
thisEvent.stopPropagation();
```

When I execute the `document.getElementById("#{id:button1}").click();` using firebug the event handler is correctly executed and the document is saved as expected. When I execute the code using another button the a page refresh is being executed but the document is not saved.

Comment: More info is required here - can you supply extensive XSP markup fragments please?

Answer (score 0):

Add a message control to see if you have any server side validation that is preventing the save. You can also try to check the "process data without validation" to see if your page is saved then.